# How does Wordpress support Unicode?

Tags: php

I've been looking through Wordpress' codes and they're mostly using PHP's regular string functions, like strlen, strpos, etc. Yet I know Wordpress supports utf8, so how does it do that?

Does it overload the regular string functions with multibyte string functions?

If so, is that a good idea in practice? If not, then how do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is written in PHP. As far as I know, PHP doesn't support any character encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...). It just assumes the text to be ASCII encoded.

The actual encoding and decoding is done by your browser. When you write a post, your browser sends the text you just entered as UTF-8 to the server. Wordpress just stores it in the database.

The encoding is specified in Wordpress' HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

This instructs the browser to use "UTF-8" for all text on the page. This includes the actual text on the page as well as all input fields.

So, Wordpress doesn't handle UTF-8 itself. It let's the browser handle it. (This is also means, if you'd specify a different encoding for the backend and the frontend pages, you'd get garbage text on the frontend.)

As a note: Unlike PHP, MySQL is UTF-8 aware. So, for example, a search for non-ASCII characters yields the correct result because the search is handled by MySQL rather than Wordpress.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Answer (score 0):

No, WordPress doesn't support unicode natively.  But it's an easy fix.

Open up your wp.config in your root.

Find these lines:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Just comment 'em out:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Now it won't display unicode as a ? ... so you're all set.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question. Wordpress has multilingual support. You can have posts and so on in utf8. I want the database charset to be utf8 and collation to be utf_general_ci. I get that part. But I have studied Wordpress' PHP files and I don't see any mb_string functions, so I'm trying to understand how Wordpress is able to work with utf8 strings!